Why do I get this error when running repl_python() in RStudio? "Error in 1L:(nrow(t) - trim_tail) : argument of length 0"
After installing and calling the reticulate package in RStudio, I can run repl_python(). However, I get the error that says "Error in 1L:(nrow(t) - trim_tail) : argument of length 0"
Example:
> repl_python()
Python 3.10.1 (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3.10)
Reticulate 1.37.0 REPL -- A Python interpreter in R.
Enter 'exit' or 'quit' to exit the REPL and return to R.
Error in 1L:(nrow(t) - trim_tail) : argument of length 0

Then, when I try to import numpy in the Python shell, I get:
> import numpy as np
Error in strsplit(formatted_python_traceback, "\n", fixed = TRUE) : 
  non-character argument

